# Java image-processing packages and conversions

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, imagej, itk

I have been using ImageJ library for handling images in Java a little bit. Now I need to be able to handle different types of data structures, such as Open CV SimpleITK and OpenImage and to be able to convert them to one another (so that it's possible to use pre-existing codes that can only handle specific types).

My first question is, what is the data structure used to represent images in ImageJ?

And then, any of you guys know of existing ways (classes/methods) to convert from one to another? I haven't found much and I think it is generally a good idea to be able to convert between all the Image types in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "how is the data structure type of ImageJ"? You say that you've used ImageJ as a library before, so I assume you're familiar with the javadoc of [`ij.ImagePlus`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/ImagePlus.html) and [`ij.process.ImageProcessor`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/process/ImageProcessor.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I have rephrased my first question. and yes I am familiar with the JavaDocs. Also my biggest issue is conversion between libraries. Thought that knowing the answer to my first question might be a good start.

Comment: There is a [SimpleITK](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-itk/) conversion layer, which you can test using the [ITK update site](http://imagej.net/ITK), designed for this purpose (running ITK code on ImageJ images). It could potentially serve as a starting point for similar OpenCV and OpenImage translation.